# column violate foreign key constraints

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to create a relationship between two tables, however i seem to get, some issues when i try to insert my object to postgres database. i keep getting following error: `insert or update on table "tournament" violates foreign key constraint "tournament_league_id_foreign"`. which i guess is related to my knex syntax?

**Insert into db**

```
      var data = {
          id: id,
          name: name,
          league_id: leagueId
      };

      var query = knex('tournament').insert(data).toString();
      query += ' on conflict (id) do update set ' + knex.raw('name = ?, updated_at = now()',[name]);

      knex.raw(query).catch(function(error) {
        log.error(error);
      })
```

**Knex tables**

```
knex.schema.createTable('league', function(table) {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('slug').unique();
    table.string('name');
    table.timestamp('created_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
    table.timestamp('updated_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
}),
knex.schema.createTable('tournament', function(table) {
    table.string('id').primary();
    table.integer('league_id').unsigned().references('id').inTable('league');
    table.string('name');
    table.boolean('resolved');
    table.timestamp('created_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
    table.timestamp('updated_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "migrate"?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. not migration! i've edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created the `tournament` table, for the column `league_id` you you specified that `.references('id').inTable('league')`. This means that for every row in that table, there must exist a row in the table `league` whose `id` is the same as the value of the `league_id` field in the former row. Apparently in your insert (is this your only insert?) you are adding a row to `tournament` whose `league_id` does not exist in `league`. As a rule, the foreign constraint (i.e. the `.references` part) implies that you must create the league first and then tournaments in that league (which actually makes sense).